# Requiring Gems With CGI And lighttpd

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cgi, lighttpd

I have configured lighttpd for CGI. Things are basically working except for requiring gems with Ruby. For example this script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'cgi'
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql2'

cgi = CGI.new

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n" 
print "Hello, world!"
```

gives me `cannot load such file -- mysql2 (LoadError)`. If I remove the `require 'mysql2'` it works fine. I installed mysql2 as root, and other users can require it without issue.

What is also odd is that `Gem.available? 'mysql2'` is `true` in the CGI script, so it seems that the gem *is* being detected in some way.

Comment: Are you using anything like `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Comment: Nope. Just plain ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, but I'm still not sure what the issue was. As root, I did

```
gem update --system
gem install --no-user-install mysql2
```

For some reason the permissions ended up wrong so I had to do

```
chmod -R o+rX /usr/local/share/gems1.9
```

Then everything worked again. Also `require 'rubygems'` ended up being unnecessary in the CGI script.